# password box show chars

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox, passwords

If passwordchar is x, then user entered password will be changed to xxxxxx, is there a way to show this password as it is instead of passwordchars, when user selects some checkbox "showpassword" ? or based on some event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to handle this yourself by swapping the PasswordBox for a TextBox bound to the same property. It would probably make sense to create a custom control to handle the interactions and state changes.

Comment: thanks derek, any sample code or link source could help much. I'm new to win7phone, not sure how to crate custom control. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you

```
 <Grid Margin="-10, 0, -10 0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <toolkit:PhoneTextBox x:Name="PasswordText"  Text="{Binding Password, ElementName=LoginPassword, Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ShowCheck,Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConveter}}"/>
                <PasswordBox x:Name="LoginPassword" Password="{Binding Text, ElementName=PasswordText, Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ShowCheck,Converter={StaticResource PasswordVisibilityConveter}}"/>
                <CheckBox Content="Show Password" Grid.Row="1" IsChecked="True" x:Name="ShowCheck" />
            </Grid>
```